# CSS scaling background bug

Tags: html, css, animation, background

I want the cloud background to scale within the box. Is that possible?

Currently it looks like this: http://freecns.yanlu.de/cumulus1/

Somehow the background scales even over the limited box. I have tried several ways to figure it out but I could not find the bug. I am not sure if it is even possible to do something like this.

I used following **HTML**:

```
<div class="backgroundbox">
    <div class="box_animation"></div>
    <ul class="nostyle inline center">
        <li class="bboxcontent left">Freecns Cumulus includes over 100 weather specific icons which are shipped as PNG, PDF, EPS and SVG. <br /></li>
        <li class="bboxvideo"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and **CSS**:

```css
.backgroundbox {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 295px;
  width: 816px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 48px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: url('http://www.yanlu.de/files/images/CloudBG.png') no-repeat center;
  padding-top: 81px;
}
.bboxcontent {
  width: 295px;
  font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.bboxvideo {
  height: 214px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow:         0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  margin-left: 8px;

  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.box_animation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('http://www.yanlu.de/files/images/CloudBG.png');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -webkit-animation-name: scale; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 40s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Comment: isn't it scaling for you already?

Comment: damn, you tricked me into watching your *movie*! I tried hard, but felt asleep after the 5th icon

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus you really should watch it!

Comment: I did, nice work, but I wanted to give you the hint to shorten the intro part ;) grüße

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus I see what you mean but I wanted it to be like this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you can set `overflow: hidden;` for `.backgroundbox` and it will snap it to the size of you box

Comment: It worked nice, there is just one problem: The rounded border is not displayed.

Comment: @Yanlu set border radius to the backgroundbox and it should work

Comment: yeah, i checked it and it doesn't work. sorry. i'm actually working now, but you are more than welcome to create a new question for that particular issue, i'd like to know the solution too :)